# How to define hasOne relationship in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have a `transaction` model that `hasOne` `stripePayment`. I want to be able to retrieve a transaction with it's associated stripePayment.

When I run the following query:

```js
const data = await models.Transaction.findOne({
  where: { clientId },
  include: [
    {
      model: models.StripePayment,
    }
  ]
});
```

It is trying to left outer join where `` Transaction`.`id` = `StripePayment`.`stripePaymentId `` when it should be the other way around. i.e. `` Transaction`.`stripePaymentId` = `StripePayment`.`id ``

My tables look something like this

transactions

```
=======
id  |  stripePaymentId     
---------------------
1   |  1a
2   |  2b
3   |  3c
4   |  4d
```

stripePayments

```
=======
id   |  amount     
---------------------
1a   |  100
2b   |  101
3c   |  102
4d   |  103
```

I then have my models with the associations defined like this:

```js
class Transaction extends Model {
  static associate(models) {
    this.hasOne(models.StripePayment, {
      foreignKey: 'id'
    });
  }
}

Transaction.init(
  {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    stripePaymentId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: true,
      foreignKey: true,
      references: {
        model: stripePayment,
        key: 'id',
      },
    }
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Transaction',
  }
);
```

and

```js
class StripePayment extends Model {
  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.Transaction, {
      foreignKey: 'stripePaymentId'
    });
  }
}

StripePayment.init(
  {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    amount: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    }
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'StripePayment',
  }
);
```

I was under the impression that a one to one relationship should have a foreign key on the origin table.

How can I tell sequelize to join on `transaction.stripePaymentId` === `stripePayment.id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `belongsTo` from a model that has `foreign key` field and `hasOne` or `hasMany` for a parent model to which another model has a reference (foreign key).
Also, you should indicate `foreignKey` option while defining associations if a foreign key column is named other than `<Child table mode>+<id>`.

```js
class Transaction extends Model {
  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.StripePayment, {
      foreignKey: 'stripePaymentId'
    });
  }
}
...
class StripePayment extends Model {
  static associate(models) {
    this.hasOne(models.Transaction, {
      foreignKey: 'stripePaymentId'
    });
  }
}
```

Please pay attention that `foreignKey` option values should be the same for pairs `belongsTo/hasOne(hasMany)`.

Comment: Thank you. It would appear I did indeed have the relations the wrong way around in the model.